# Get 8 shorts from a short

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, short

I have an array `a` of short like this one:

```
a = [ 16748, 
      26979, 
      25888, 
      30561, 
      115
    ] //in decimal

a = [ 0100000101101100, 
      0110100101100011, 
      0110010100100000, 
      0111011101100001, 
      0000000001110011
    ] //in binary
```

I would like to obtain another array `b` of shorts composed by representing each pair of bits of each short.
(It's diffucult to explain but easy to understand using an example).

So, for the array `a` I will obtain array `b`:

```
b = [ 01, 00, 00, 01, 01, 10, 11, 00, 
      01, 10, 10, 01, 01, 10, 00, 11, 
      01, 10, 01, 01, 00, 10, 00, 00, 
      01, 11, 01, 11, 01, 10, 00, 01, 
      00, 00, 00, 00, 01, 11, 00, 11
    ]
```

In pseudocode I thought of doing so:

```
int lenght = (16/2) * a.length; //16*2 because I had short (16 bit) and I want sequences of 2 bit
short[] b = new short[length]; //I create the new array of short
int j = 0; //counter of b array
foreach n in a { //foreach short in array a
    for(int i = 16 - 2; i > 0; i-2) { //shift of 2 positions to right
        b[j] = ( (n >> i) & ((2^2)-1) ); //shift and &
        j++;
    }
}
```

I tried to translate this pseudocode (assumnig it's correct) to Java:

```
public static short[] createSequencesOf2Bit(short[] a) {
    int length = (16/2) * a.length; 
    short[] b = new short[length];

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        int j = 0; 
        for(short c = 16 - 2; c > 0; c -= 2) {
            short shift = (short)(a[i] >> c);
            b[j] = (short)(shift & 0x11);
            j++;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

But if I print `b[]` I don't obtain what I want. 
For example, considering only the first short in `a` `(16748 = 0100000101101100)`. 
I obtain:

```
[1, 0, 16, 1, 1, 16, 17]
```

That is completely wrong. Infact I should get:

```
b = [ 01, 00, 00, 01, 01, 10, 11, 00,
      ...
    ] //in binary

b = [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0,
      ...
    ] //in decimal
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks a lot.

---

That's strange. If I consider only the first short in a and I print b I get:

```
public static short[] createSequencesOf2Bit(short[] a) {
    int length = (16/2) * a.length; 
    short[] b = new short[length];

    //for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        int j = 0; 
        for(short c = (16 - 2); c >= 0; c -= 2) {
            short shift = (short)(a[0] >> c);
            b[j] = (short)(shift & 0x3);
            j++;
        }
    //}
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("b[" + i + "]: " + b[i]);
    }
    return b;
} 

b = [1 0 0 1 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 ... 0]
```

But if I print this one:

```
public static short[] createSequencesOf2Bit(short[] a) {
    int length = (16/2) * a.length; 
    short[] b = new short[length];

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        int j = 0; 
        for(short c = (16 - 2); c >= 0; c -= 2) {
            short shift = (short)(a[i] >> c);
            b[j] = (short)(shift & 0x3);
            j++;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("b[" + i + "]: " + b[i]);
    }
    return b;
} 

b = [0 0 0 0 1 3 0 3 0 0 0 0 ... 0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the main issue is that instead of `& 0x11` you want `& 0x3`.  Remember that `0x` means hexadecimal, so `0x11` gives you the number 17, not 3.  Or you could write `0b11` to get `11` in binary.

Additionally, as pointed out in the comments, the loop condition should be `c >= 0`, not `c > 0`.

Comment: And secondly the loop condition is wrong:  `c > 0`, should be ` c >= 0`.

Comment: Ok, thanks to both but now I get `b = [0 0 0 0 1 3 0 3 0 0 0 0 ... 0]`.

Comment: @Step your problem is because you reset `j` for every element in the array, so you only ever fill the first eight spots in the array.

Comment: @Step : move `int j = 0; ` before the first loop.